# Event listener on DOMContentLoaded fires randomly

Tags: javascript, domcontentloaded

I have a script on a page which is working most of the time but not always, and I'd like to know why.

This script is imported via:

```
<script src="script.js" async></script>` tag in `<head>
```

And the content of the script is:

```
console.log("loading"); // always gets printed
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    console.log("outer"); // sometimes get not printed
    (function() {
        console.log("inner"); // sometimes get not printed
    })();
});
```

The browser console always outputs `loading` but sometimes it doesn't output the rest (both `outer` and `inner`). Doing either a hard refresh on the page or simply reloading it (hitting `Enter` on the address bar) doesn't seem to influence this behavior (same results each way).

I'll also add that `outer` and `inner` are always printed by pair, there is never one without the other.

Is there a problem in the way I'm listening to `DOMContentLoaded`? Or would I have to load the script outside `<head>` (which I would prefer not to, if possible)?

Comment: I just recreated an example here. I get all 3 messages 100% of the time. What browser are you testing this in?

Comment: Does your URL in the address bar have a hash, like `#foobar`? I seem to remember something about the page not fully refreshing when that's the case, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @nils same on Safari, Chrome, Firefox, Safari iOS, Chrome iOS

Comment: @squint same result with or without a hash

Comment: May I add that the script is loaded from a remote location, if it helps?

Comment: And seeing from your example, you don't have an `asyc` or `defer` attribute on your code either. Usually, your code should be render-blocking and execute before the rest of the html is parsed.

Comment: @nils actually I didn't mentioned it but yes the script is loaded with `async`

Comment: …that is kind of an important detail, especially since your code above does not have that attribute. Obviously `async` is the problem.

Comment: So, sometimes the code is loaded *after* `DOMContentLoaded` has been fired..., right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`async` script tags are executed as soon as the code has been loaded, regardless of whether the DOM content has been loaded or not. So in general, do not use this for DOM-relevant operations.

Instead, if you want your file to load but your code to execute only after `DOMContentLoaded`, use the `defer` attribute. You wont need an event listener in your code in this case:

[image]
<sub>Image Source: http://peter.sh/experiments/asynchronous-and-deferred-javascript-execution-explained/</sub>

A word of caution though, [`defer` is buggy in IE9 and below.](http://caniuse.com/#search=defer)

Comment: Nice and smooth - thanks for everything (answer, explanations...)

Comment: You're welcome :) Just for your next question, please include all the relevant details ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your script is executing **after** the DOMContentLoaded event has been fired, so it's too late to set up a listener.